# How do I implement an abstract method with different parameters?

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement an abstract class in order to make my code more readable.

This is my TvShow class:

```
final class TvShow {

private const DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_SEASONS = 3;
private const DEFAULT_DELIVERED = false;
private const DEFAULT_TITLE = "";
private const DEFAULT_GENDER = "";
private const DEFAULT_CREATOR = "";

private function __construct(
    private string $title = self::DEFAULT_TITLE,
    private string $creator = self::DEFAULT_CREATOR,
    private int $seasons = self::DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_SEASONS,
    private string $gender = self::DEFAULT_GENDER,
    private bool $delivered = self::DEFAULT_DELIVERED
) {}

public static function createWithTitleAndCreator(string $title, string $creator):self {
    return new self($title, $creator);
}

public static function create(string $tile, string $creator, int $seasons, string $gender):self {
    return new self($tile, $creator, $seasons, $gender);
}

public function compareTo(object $object): bool {
    if($this->seasons > $object->numberOfSeasons()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function numberOfSeasons() {
    return $this->seasons;
}
```

}

And this is my Videogame class:

```
final class Videogame {

private const DEFAULT_HOURS = 10;
private const DEFAULT_DELIVERED = false;
private const DEFAULT_TITLE = "";
private const DEFAULT_GENDER = "";
private const DEFAULT_COMPANY = "";

public function __construct(
    private string $title = self::DEFAULT_TITLE,
    private int $estimatedHours = self::DEFAULT_HOURS,
    private string $gender = self::DEFAULT_GENDER,
    private string $company = self::DEFAULT_COMPANY,
    private bool $delivered = self::DEFAULT_DELIVERED
) {}

public static function createWithTitleAndHours(string $title, int $estimatedHours):self {
    return new self($title, $estimatedHours);
}

public static function create(string $title, int $estimatedHours, string $gender, string $company):self {
    return new self($title, $estimatedHours, $gender, $company);
}

public function compareTo(object $object): bool {
    if($this->estimatedHours > $object->numberOfHours()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function numberOfHours() {
    return $this->estimatedHours;
}
```

}

By having the compareTo() method repeated, I have chosen to implement an abstract class:

```
abstract class Product {

abstract protected function compareTo(object $object);
```

}

But I need to change the type "object" depending the class to prevent errors. For example:

```
public function compareTo(TvShow $object): bool {
    if($this->seasons > $object->numberOfSeasons()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code return an error

The excercise require to implement the method in an abstract class. How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Have `TvShow` and `VideoGame` extend a parent class or implement an interface. Use the parent (generic) class as the hinted type. PHP Doesn't offer `override` in the way some other languages do.

Comment: Better even create an interface that both classes implement. Something like "Comparable".

Comment: Have the same problem, I can't filter by type of object if i implement interface

Comment: remove the "abstract protected function compareTo(object $object);" from the parent and you can have whatever function definition you like in your child classes

Comment: But I can't repeat code

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this then, as @arkascha commented use an interface that both classes implement

```
interface ComparableInterface {}

final class TvShow implements ComparableInterface {
...

final class Videogame implements ComparableInterface {
...


public function compareTo(ComparableInterface $object): bool {
    $class = get_class($object);

    switch ($class) {
      case TvShow::class:
         return ($this->seasons > $object->numberOfSeasons());
        
      case ...


}
```